# CodeIgniter query: How to move a column value to another column in the same row and save the current time in the original column?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-update

In my db table, I have two datetime columns: `Last` and `Current`. These column allow me to keep track of when someone last used a valid login to the service I am building up.

Using CodeIgniter's active record, is it possible to update a row so that the `Last` value receives the `Current` value AND then the `Current` value is replace with the current datetime?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758415/swap-values-for-two-rows-in-the-same-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$data = array('current_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$this->db->set('last_login', 'current_login', false);
$this->db->where('id', 'some_id');
$this->db->update('login_table', $data);
```

Pay particular attention to the `set()` call's 3rd parameter.  `false` prevents CodeIgniter from quoting the 2nd parameter -- this allows the value to be treated as a table column and not a string value.  For any data that doesn't need to special treatment, you can lump all of those declarations into the `$data` array.

The query generated by above code:

```
UPDATE `login_table`
SET last_login = current_login, `current_login` = '2018-01-18 15:24:13'
WHERE `id` = 'some_id'
```

Comment: how can we do it if we need to perform  
`$this->db->set('some_column','some_column+$some_data');`

Comment: @krishnachalise If it is number to add,`$this->db->set('some_column','some_column+$some_data',false)`

Comment: Or if string to concat,
`$this->db->set('some_column','CONCAT(some_column,\''.$some_data.'\')',false);`

Comment: what if only wants to move column and not update current_login date. what would be this statement like $this->db->update('login_table', $data); ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array( 
    'name'      => $_POST['name'] , 
    'groupname' => $_POST['groupname'], 
    'age'       => $_POST['age']
);

$this->db->where('id', $_POST['id']);

$this->db->update('tbl_user', $data);
```

Comment: irrelevant answer 

Comment: I agree with @Loki This answer does not attempt to solve the question asked.  This is merely updating a row with user-submitted data.  The question, which is suitably answered by Rajeev is how to update one column value using another column's value in the same row.  This answer is simply wrong (or the positive way to spin it -- This is the correct answer to a different question.  Furthermore, this is a code-only answer which means it is a low-value post on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to upgrade only a single column of a table row then you can use as following:

```
$this->db->set('column_header', $value); //value that used to update column  
$this->db->where('column_id', $column_id_value); //which row want to upgrade  
$this->db->update('table_name');  //table name
```

Comment: This answer does not attempt to solve the question asked. This is merely updating a row with the value in a variable. The question, which is suitably answered by Rajeev is how to update one column value using another column's value in the same row. This answer is simply wrong (or the positive way to spin it -- This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and I would like to provide a slight alternative to Rajeev's answer that does not pass a php-generated datetime formatted string to the query.

The important distinction about how to declare the values to be SET in the UPDATE query is that they must not be quoted as literal strings.

To prevent CodeIgniter from doing this "favor" automatically, use the `set()` method with a third parameter of `false`.

```
$userId = 444;
$this->db->set('Last', 'Current', false);
$this->db->set('Current', 'NOW()', false);
$this->db->where('Id', $userId);
// return $this->db->get_compiled_update('Login');  // uncomment to see the rendered query
$this->db->update('Login');
return $this->db->affected_rows();  // this is expected to return the integer: 1
```

The generated query (depending on your database adapter) would be like this:

```
UPDATE `Login` SET Last = Current, Current = NOW() WHERE `Id` = 444
```

Demonstrated proof that the query works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vcc6PfMcYhDD87wZE5gBtw/0

In this case, `Last` and `Current` ARE MySQL Keywords, but they are not Reserved Keywords, so they don't *need* to be backtick-wrapped.

If your precise query needs to have properly quoted identifiers (table/column names), then there is always [protectIdentifiers()](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#protecting-identifiers).