# Django update() to swap values of two fields in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django

The following does not work:

```
Car.objects.filters(<filter>).update(x=F('y'), y=F('x'))
```

as both `x` and `y` ends up being the same value.

I need to use update() instead of save() due to performance (large set of records).

Are there any other way of doing an update like the one above to mimic Python's `x, y = y, x`?

The db is MySQL, [which might explain why the resulting SQL statement doesn't work](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31045/swap-columns-on-some-rows/31052#31052).

Comment: This is the way that SQL behaves. for example `UPDATE myapp_car set x=y,y=x` would set both to y

Comment: @e4c5 no it wouldn't. It is just that **MySQL** is broken and perhaps that is what you and Tomas are using.

Comment: Well, I do have three RDBMS but unfortunately for me I tried this only one mysql, should have also tried on postgresql @AnttiHaapala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work correctly if you're using a proper standard-compliant SQL database. The query would expand to

```
UPDATE car SET x = y, y = x WHERE <filter>
```

It would work correctly at least on [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660/918959) (also below), SQLite3 (below), [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql#comment17537164_37660) and [MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198587/how-do-i-swap-column-values-in-sql-server-2008), however the MySQL implementation is broken.

PostgreSQL:

```
select * from car;
    x    |  y   
---------+------
 prefect | ford
(1 row)

test=> update car set x = y, y = x;
UPDATE 1
test=> select * from car;
  x   |    y    
------+---------
 ford | prefect
(1 row)
```

SQLite3

```
sqlite> select * from foo;
prefect|ford
sqlite> update foo set x = y, y = x;
sqlite> select * from foo;
ford|prefect
```

However, MySQL violates the SQL standard,

```
mysql> insert into car values ('prefect', 'ford');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from car;
+---------+------+
| x       | y    |
+---------+------+
| prefect | ford |
+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update car set x = y, y = x;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from car;
+------+------+
| x    | y    |
+------+------+
| ford | ford |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thus there is a portable way to do this using a standard-compliant SQL database, but MySQL isn't one of them. If you cannot use the `for` ... `save` loop, then you must resort to some of the hacks from [Swapping column vales in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649/swapping-column-values-in-mysql); the temporary variable seems to be the most generic one; though I am not sure whether you can use the temporary variables with `F` constructs of Django.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think update can do that as it's basically an sql wrapper.
What you could do, though, is use save(values=['x','y']). Hopefully it won't be as slow.
Alternatively, you could use raw sql from django to perform the swap (see [Swap values for two rows in the same table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758415/swap-values-for-two-rows-in-the-same-table-in-sql-server))