# How to swap rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have these rows in SQL Server:

[image: screenshot from management studio]

How can I swap the data circled in red?

Comment: Please consider reading up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap values for two rows in the same table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758415/swap-values-for-two-rows-in-the-same-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: thank you for editing @Joel Coehoorn

Comment: It's still bad. Screenshots of sample data, results, code, etc, are NOT OKAY.

Comment: Also, please show what you've tried already, and the result you got.

Comment: What do you even mean by "swap"? As in the values for Room 9103 should appear for 9104, and 9103 should show `NULL`? Is that only in your `SELECT`, or are you looking to `UPDATE` the value of the rows? What have *you* tried so far, and why didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the original values in a temporary table with the IDs swapped then join to the temporary table whilst updating the table, example code below:

```
--drop temp table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

--need to store the original values
SELECT
    *,CASE WHEN Room_Number=9104 then 9103 ELSE 9104 END AS New_Room_Number
    INTO #Temp
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Room_Number in (9103,9104)

--swap values
UPDATE y
    SET Check_IN=t.Check_IN
        ,Check_OUT=t.Check_OUT
        ,FullName=t.FullName
        ,ContactNumber=t.ContactNumber
        ,Amount=t.Amount
    FROM YourTable        y
        INNER JOIN #Temp  t ON y.Room_Number =t.New_Room_Number
    WHERE y.Room_Number in (9103,9104)
```

Comment: You need to alias that new column differently. Resulting temp table would have two Room_Number columns

Comment: I received, Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'ID'.

Comment: `ID` is probably mean to be `Room_Number`, @NayjArugay. One of the reasons why images are bad; we don't have to transcribe your data if post it as **formatted** `text`.

Comment: I changed it to Room_Number, I still received error at the bottom line. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'New_Room_Number'.

Comment: @Larnu, this is just my inability to copy and paste, I've edited my answer

Comment: I am still receiving an error.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'New_Room_Number'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Ambiguous column name 'Room_Number'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Ambiguous column name 'Room_Number'.

Comment: @NayjArugay, I've edited to solve for the ambiguous column name, you might need to start a new query or drop the temp table to resolve the other error

Comment: @Ryan Sparks thank you for your help but I still received an error. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'New_Room_Number'.

Comment: @NayjArugay your comments imply you don't understand the answer here. Understanding is really important, as it's you who has to support the SQL, not anyone here (including Ryan), If you don't understand you should be asking about it, not asking Ryan to debug the (simple) things.

Comment: @Larnu whilst I agree, I probably should have tested my answer to begin with, which I've now done with the test data: CREATE TABLE YourTable (Room_Number NVARCHAR(MAX), Check_IN NVARCHAR(MAX), Check_OUT NVARCHAR(MAX), FullName NVARCHAR(MAX), ContactNumber NVARCHAR(MAX), Amount NVARCHAR(MAX))

insert yourtable values (9104, null, null, null, null, null), (9103, 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a')

Comment: Thank you! it works now. I've searched for my error. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with you answer @Ryan Sparks. Thank you.

Comment: I've appreciated your help guys.

Comment: @Larnu I'm new to SQL. It just happened that I need to learn it to store my project in Java.

Comment: Being new is fine, @NayjArugay , but when getting an answer to a question on Stack Overflow it's important that you understand it, as it's you that has to support it in the end. If you don't understand it, that's a problem as it means you end up having to ask questions again to do more of the work. You learn by asking how something works, or taking the time understand how something does, not by having the work done for you.